# React App development behind Nginx

Tags: reactjs, nginx, create-react-app

I have a legacy angular app and a new react app that I want to expose through nginx.

I have a production nginx config that has the static files, but I was trying to get dev to work as well - with the hot-reload and the webpack dev server. I have this working as it should, but I realized it would be better if I can scope the react with /r/ and angular app with /a/. However, with the config below, whenever I go to `localhost/r/`, the bundle.js lives in `/static/`. Is there a way to make `/static/` to `/r/static/` for the react app?

Is there a better way of doing this?

```
location /r {
  proxy_pass http://172.17.0.2:3000;
  proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
location /static/ {
  proxy_pass http://172.17.0.2:3000;
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
location /sockjs-node/ {
  proxy_pass http://172.17.0.2:3000;
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @HappyCry for showing a way to hot-reload 'npm start' app on nginx proxy.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a way to do that:

```
location /static/ {
  proxy_pass http:/172.17.0.2:3000/r/static/
  ...
}
```

Check out [the nginx.org docs for proxy_pass](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass).